# How do I complete the Navi-Gator maze?

Tags: later-alligator

The power went out at the hotel starting a minigame Navi-Gator. I need to navigate in the dark to reach The Event but I can't figure out where to go. What path do I need to take to escape this maze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reach the end of the Navi-Gator maze:

- From the start of the maze, walk down until you reach a corner.
- Keep going right until you hit a wall in a hallway with wooden floorboards.
- Go down towards a large open room with a carpet.
- Exit the room using the hallway on the bottom-left
- Walk left for a little bit then go down until you hit a wall.
- Go right until you reach a corner.
- Go around the corner and continue going right past a set of cracked floor tiles into a dark room.
- Go up until you hit a wall in a hall with wooden floorboards.
- Go right, then straight up until you hit a wall.
- Go right into the tiled-wooden floor.
- Continue going up until you reach the exit.

For a video demonstration, see 1:50:04 in the video below.